# Get positive and negative part of gradient for loss function in PyTorch

Tags: matrix, pytorch, mathematical-optimization, gradient-descent, autograd

I want to implement non-negative matrix factorization using PyTorch.  Here is my initial implement:

```py
def nmf(X, k, lr, epochs):
    # X: input matrix of size (m, n)
    # k: number of latent factors
    # lr: learning rate
    # epochs: number of training epochs
    m, n = X.shape
    W = torch.rand(m, k, requires_grad=True)  # initialize W randomly
    H = torch.rand(k, n, requires_grad=True)  # initialize H randomly
    # training loop
    for i in range(epochs):
        # compute reconstruction error
        loss = torch.norm(X - torch.matmul(W, H), p='fro')
        # compute gradients
        loss.backward()
        # update parameters using additive update rule
        with torch.no_grad():
            W -= lr * W.grad
            H -= lr * H.grad
            W.grad.zero_()
            H.grad.zero_()
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {i}: loss = {loss.item()}")
    return W.detach(), H.detach()
```

Lee and Seung in [this paper](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1861-algorithms-for-non-negative-matrix-factorization.pdf), proposed to use adaptive learning rates to avoid subtraction and thus the production of negative elements. [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/352921/312701) is the stats.SE thread where I get some idea. But I don't know how to implement **multiplicative update rule** for W,H in pytorch, as it need to separate the positive and negative part of their gradient respectively. **Yes, I can manually implement that but I want to leverage this to the torch autograd.**

[image]

Any idea how to manage to do so? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the multiplicative update rule, the positive and negative parts of the gradients are separated and the updates are computed based on the ratio of the positive and negative parts.

Note: small value eps is added to the denominators to avoid division by zero.

```
def nmf(X, k, lr, epochs):
    # X: input matrix of size (m, n)
    # k: number of latent factors
    # lr: learning rate
    # epochs: number of training epochs
    m, n = X.shape
    W = torch.rand(m, k, requires_grad=True)  # initialize W randomly
    H = torch.rand(k, n, requires_grad=True)  # initialize H randomly
    eps = 1e-9  # small value to avoid division by zero
    # training loop
    for i in range(epochs):
        # compute reconstruction error
        loss = torch.norm(X - torch.matmul(W, H), p='fro')
        # compute gradients
        W_pos = torch.relu(W)  # separate positive and negative parts of W
        W_neg = torch.relu(-W)
        H_pos = torch.relu(H)  # separate positive and negative parts of H
        H_neg = torch.relu(-H)
        grad_W_pos = torch.matmul((torch.matmul(W_pos, H_pos) - X), H_pos.t())
        grad_W_neg = torch.matmul((torch.matmul(W_neg, H_pos) - X), H_pos.t())
        grad_H_pos = torch.matmul(W_pos.t(), (torch.matmul(W_pos, H_pos) - X))
        grad_H_neg = torch.matmul(W_pos.t(), (torch.matmul(W_pos, H_neg) - X))
        # update parameters using multiplicative update rule
        W *= torch.sqrt((grad_W_pos + eps) / (grad_W_neg + eps))
        H *= torch.sqrt((grad_H_pos + eps) / (grad_H_neg + eps))
        if i % 10 == 0:
            print(f"Epoch {i}: loss = {loss.item()}")
    return W.detach(), H.detach()
```

However, implementing adaptive learning rates in PyTorch for NMF can be more complex and may require additional code

Comment: Can you explain how applying relu help to get the positive and negative part of the gradients? Actually, I am doing something similar, hence interested to know the solution! @RajeshKontham

Comment: When the 'relu' function is applied to a tensor, it sets any negative values to zero, while leaving positive values unchanged.
relu is applied separately to the positive and negative parts of the factor matrices W and H. This allows the gradients to be separated into positive and negative components.

Comment: Sorry for late response, @RajeshKontham. Using relu to separate the gradients part seem promising. But I didn't see how you backpropagate the gradients. Isn't there should be `loss.backward()`? I am new in PyTorch. After give it a try I get, `Epoch 0: loss = 11363.654656173509
Epoch 10: loss = nan
Epoch 20: loss = nan` seems like something is not working after 1st iteration.

Comment: Backpropagation is not needed in this case. 
NaN after the first epoch suggests that there may be a numerical instability or a division by zero occurring during the computation. 
A Issue is the use of the torch.sqrt function in the update rule, which can result in NaN values if the argument is negative.
Solution: using the torch.clamp function to bound the factor matrices W and H to be non-negative. This prevents the computation of negative values that cause numerical issues. You can try reducing the learning rate lr to improve stability.